# Checkbox Dropdown not shown correctly

Tags: javascript, html, flask, checkbox, drop-down-menu

**Solution:**
I referenced the css and the other js file in the wrong way, in flask, it has to be done like this:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename="js/jquery.multiselect.js")}}"></script>
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/jquery.multiselect.css') }}">
```

I created a dropdown list with checkboxes (or at least I tried to) with this guide: https://www.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/
However, the dropdown isn't displayed correctly and looks like shown in the picture. 
My html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">$
<script src="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css">
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename="js/drug_response.js")}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="drug" multiple id="drug">
    {% for drug in drugs %}
            {% if drug == current_drug %}
                    <option selected value="{{ drug }}">{{ drug }}</option>
            {% else %}
                    <option value="{{ drug }}">{{ drug }}</option>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</body>
```

and my js:

```
$('select[multiple]').multiselect();
$('#drug').multiselect({
columns: 1,
placeholder: 'Select drugs'
});
```

Edit: changed js to:

```
$(function(){
 $drug_list = $('#drug');
    $drug_list.multiselect();
    });
```

but did not help.

I am not that proficient in front end development, so I am at a loss right now as to what might be going wrong.

[image: ...why?]

Comment: Check in the inspector what the request status is from multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css, is it correctly loaded?

Comment: @JQuest Where in the inspector do I find that information?

Comment: Ok, found it and you were right, I didn't reference it correctly...